# Finding All Subset Sum and Combinational Sum using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sum, subset, combinations

I have these lists
Level 2 = 23
Level 3 = 34
Level 4 = 45
Level 5 = 56
Level 6 =  68
Level 7 = 79
Level 8 = 90
Level 9 = 101
Level 10 = 112
Level 11 = 123
Level 12 = 134
Level 13 = 145
Level 14 = 156
Level 15 = 168
Level 16 = 179

The numbers of each Level  is for arrays to Find all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given set

**MY CODE**

```
  index.html
  <html>  
    <body>  
    <form method="post" action="compute.php">  
      Current:  
     <input type="number" name="number1" />  
   <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Compute">  
  </form> 
    </body>
  </html>

 compute.php
   <?php 

   $number1 = $_POST['number1']; 
   $limit =  100000-$number1;  

   $array = array (23,34,45,56,68,79,90,101,112,123,134,145,156,168,179);

   $array = array_filter($array, function($var) use ($limit) {
   return ($var <= $limit);
   });

    rsort($array);
  $num = count($array); 
  $total = pow(2, $num);
   $out = array();

   for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) { 

$comb = array();
for ($j = 0; $j < $num; $j++) { 
   // is bit $j set in $i? 
    if (pow(2, $j) & $i){
      $comb[] = $array[$j];
    }      
} 

if (array_sum($comb) == $limit)
{
  $out[] = $comb;
}
}

 array_multisort(array_map('count', $out), SORT_ASC, $out);

  $out = array_unique($out, SORT_REGULAR);
$m = 1;
 foreach($out as $result) 

  echo "<b>Possible Answer ". $m++. " : </b> " .implode(', ', $result)." 
 <br><br>";


  ?>
  </div> 
  </div>
```

**My Input and Ouput**

If i input 99318
the output is like this
Possible Answer 1 : 168, 145, 134, 123, 112

Possible Answer 2 : 168, 156, 134, 123, 101

Possible Answer 3 : 168, 156, 145, 112, 101

my problem is my code cannot find the combinations array if its repeated numbers like this (112) 
Possible Answer : 168, 156, 134, 112, 112

right now im confused how to find and get the repeated numbers

and how i combine the words "Level 10" and "exp" to results and combine the same subset (the 112) like this
Possible Answer : Level 15 - 168 exp, Level 14 - 156 exp, Level 10 - 134 exp, Level 10 (2x) - 224 exp

Comment: I didn't understand. Can you be more clear about the input and expected output(with proper indendation) ?

Comment: That's unclear. What is this result `( Possible Answer 1 : Level 9 - 101 exp, Level 8 - 90 exp )`? What does it mean? What does the array `(23,34,45,56,68,79,90,101,112,123,134,145,156,168,179)` have any relevance here? You will have to explain all these in your post.

Comment: Sorry to say, but I am unable to understand what's all these numbers. Maybe you can ask a new question with a single requirement and so on, so that we could figure out whole piece of the puzzle step by step.

Comment: You need to give us a proper explanation of what logic your script is supposed to follow here, _how_ you get from those input values to the desired output. _“I want the output must be like this ( Possible Answer 1 : Level 3 (2x) - 68 exp, Level 1 - 23 exp )”_ - based on _what_? That is currently absolutely, massively unclear.

Comment: I already update again.